# How to remove all jquery live events from javascript widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, widget, live

I'm developing some javascript widget which loaded on many other sites.

When widget are loading I bind jquery live event on links and buttons.
For instance:

```
$('.my-submit').live('click', function() {...});
...
$('.my-link').live('click', function() {...});
```

So the question is how can I remove all live events only for widget links and buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to bind with a namespace, and remove all the namespaced events:

```
$('.my-submit').live('click.myPlugin', function() {...});
```

You can then call [`die`](http://api.jquery.com/die) with the namespace:

```
$('.my-submit').die('click.myPlugin'); // only myPlugin events are removed
```

Better yet is to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off) functionality introduced in jQuery 1.7. This is a far superior way to handle binding and unbinding events:

```
$(document).on('click.myPlugin', '.my-submit', function() {...}))
           .on('click.myPlugin', '.my-link', function() {...}));

$(document).off('click.myPlugin'); // remove all myPlugin functions
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.die()`:

> Remove all event handlers previously attached using .live() from the
>   elements.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/die/*

On a side-note, you should move from using `.live()` to `.delegate()` (or `.on()` depending on your version of jQuery) because it will improve performance and `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.

```
$(<selector>).live(<event>, <handler>);
```

is the same as:

```
$(document).delegate(<selector>, <event>, <handler>);
```

The bonus to using `.delegate()` is that you can choose your root-element (you aren't forced to use `document`).

Some docs for ya:

- `.die()`: http://api.jquery.com/die
- `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: If you're jQuery 1.7+, I would reverse the order of priority that Jasper suggests-- go directly to `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`, since the latter is an alias of the former that is more likely to itself be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Point of reference jQuery themselves:

From [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Use on or delegate and this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the JQuery.unbind() method. You would use it like this:

```
$.('.my-link').unbind('click');
```

Hope this helps.